# How to render multiple html pages with node.js express?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, visual-studio-code

Want to accomplish this:

```
<html>
<!-- head -->
<head>
    <title>SpaceGame2</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/spaceGame.css">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css"> -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

    <p class="testing"></p> html page

    <!-- Footer -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

by seperating it in 3 separate files, head.html, footer.html and main.html. 
main.html will vary but the other two will be the same.

code:

```
var express = require('express');
var partial = require('express-partial');
var app = express();

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Listening on port 3000');
});

var path = require("path");
app.use(express.static(path.resolve('./')));
app.use(express.static(path.resolve('./Static')))
app.use(express.static(path.resolve('./Views')))
var partial = require('express-partial');
var url = require('url');

app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    var path = require("path");

    var pathname = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
    var originPoint = GetOriginPoint(pathname);
    if (pathname == "" || pathname == "/") {
        pathname = "/OverView";
    }

    // res.renderPartials({
    //     Head: { data: path.resolve('./Views/Layout/head') },
    //     Main: { data: path.resolve('./Views' + originPoint + pathname + '.html') },
    //     Head: { data: path.resolve('./Views/Layout/footer') },
    // });


     res.sendFile(path.resolve('./Views' + originPoint + pathname + '.html'));
});
```

Tried importing the files in html tags, tried using renderpartials and it did not work, the only way i know that I can do this is by loading the main page and have a custom script that fetches the two html pages from the server but this is not desiered, I assume there is something like :

```
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
       var content = [];

      content.push("head.html")
      content.push("main.html")
      content.push("footer.html")

     res.sendFile(content);

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some thinkering I decided to go with express-handlerbars to solve this:

```
var hbs = require('express-handlebars');

app.engine('hbs', hbs({ extname: 'hbs', defaultLayout: 'layout', layoutsDir: orgininPath.resolve('./Views/Layout/') }));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
```

the hbs file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Static/css/spaceGame.css">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css"> -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>{{title}}</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{{body}}}

        <!-- Footer -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Static/script/someTest.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does your Express route code look like to build this?

Answer (score 0):

Using the [EJS templating language](http://www.embeddedjs.com) w/ Express you will be able to reach any goal in marking up your HTML. 
Just install in via npm (example: `npm link ejs` at your project location).

Then set express engine to ejs `app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

After you do it just call a `render` method

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  // render `index.ejs` with some data
  res.render('index', { variable: 'value' })
});
```

Comment: judging form a fast read I will need to have some kind of value indicator in my html, like <%Head here%> which is not what I want. I would like to add 3 html documents as one and send them to the client, is this possible?

Comment: How can you make the 'variable' render HTML/CSS/JavaScript? It will essentially go through as text and not compile in the DOM.